# Fix GPT after using dd to clone a smaller disk onto a larger disk

Tags: disk, gpt, parted, cloning

I used dd to clone a smaller disk onto a larger disk, however now when booting I'm getting dmesg errors of:

```
[Fri Sep 30 11:48:43 2022] GPT:Primary header thinks Alt. header is not at the end of the disk.
[Fri Sep 30 11:48:43 2022] GPT:1953525167 != 3907029167
[Fri Sep 30 11:48:43 2022] GPT:Alternate GPT header not at the end of the disk.
[Fri Sep 30 11:48:43 2022] GPT:1953525167 != 3907029167
[Fri Sep 30 11:48:43 2022] GPT: Use GNU Parted to correct GPT errors.
```

How can I resolve this? The error indicates to use parted, but I'm unsure as to what commands to run?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to do anything special, just use `p` to print information about the disk, parted will tell you the partition table is wrong and ask you what to do so simply tell it to `Fix` it:

```
# parted /dev/loop0
GNU Parted 3.5
Using /dev/loop0
Welcome to GNU Parted! Type 'help' to view a list of commands.
(parted) p                                                                
Warning: Not all of the space available to /dev/loop0 appears to be used, you can fix the GPT to use all of the space (an extra 10485760 blocks) or continue with the current setting? 
Fix/Ignore? Fix
...
```

(of course replace `/dev/loop0` with your disk, e.g. `/dev/sda`).